# installing compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

Following the instructions in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compojure/Getting_Started, I:

- downloaded http://github.com/weavejester/compojure/tarball/0.3.2
- extracted to ~/compojure
- chdir to there
- changed permission to executable
- run ant deps
- ant
- run export CLASSPATH=~/compojure/compojure.jar
- created compojure shell script
- Clojure source file
- chdir to there
- run ./compojure hello.clj

Then, I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/Script
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.lang.Script
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: clojure.lang.Script. Program will exit.
```

I tried changing Compojure shell script to use full classpath, but still didn't work.

Why not? How to install Compojure?

Answer (score 4):

That page is outdated.

You should follow these instructions from compojure developers:
https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: @Delirium: Also, you should start using a build tool like maven2 or leiningen to do things like setting up classpath, as soon as you can.

Comment: *If* you can get leiningen to work...  That's been my problem...  :-(

Comment: Extremely useful.  I've been looking on and off all day for how to get Compojure set up correctly.